# In python, my array value changes by itself, why?

Tags: python

```
print(ys)
for i in range(counter):
    if(ys[i]<yzero[i]):
        dupys[i]=yzero[i]
#plt.plot(xs,dupys) #this is used for checking on the levelline graph
print(ys)
```

I have try many different ways to test it out, but it seems like it changes by itself for no reason, from the code, we can see that the I only change the dupys list.

> output:
>
> > [-1.401109325007359, -1.4012097591798365, -1.4013107885799283, -1.4013711090958765, -1.4013991265977308,...]
> >
> > [-1.4, -1.4, -1.4, -1.4, -1.4, -1.4, -1.4, -1.4, -1.4, -1.4, -1.4, -1.4, ...]

Comment: Looks like `dupys` is the same list as `ys`. Post a [mcve] and we can say for sure.

Comment: Is `dupys` just `dupys = ys`?  Because then both ientifiers refer to the same list.

Comment: unclear representation of problem

Comment: Did you try to find the reason.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List changes unexpectedly after assignment. Why is this and how can I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/list-changes-unexpectedly-after-assignment-why-is-this-and-how-can-i-prevent-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if a part of the code is missing, I suppose you're facing the following problem:

```
dear_old_value = ["rusty_value0", "rusty_value1", "rusty_value2", "rusty_value3"]

new_values = dear_old_value

new_values[0] = "shiny_value0"
new_values[2] = "shiny_value2"

print dear_old_value # OUTPUT: ['shiny_value0', 'rusty_value1', 'shiny_value2', 'rusty_value3']
```

as you see, even if you're modifying values in the new list, also the old one gets modified.
To work around this problem, you should assign to the new list a copy of the old one:

```
dear_old_value = ["rusty_value0", "rusty_value1", "rusty_value2", "rusty_value3"]

new_values = list(dear_old_value)

new_values[0] = "shiny_value0"
new_values[2] = "shiny_value2"

print dear_old_value # OUTPUT: ['rusty_value0', 'rusty_value1', 'rusty_value2', 'rusty_value3']
```

In Python, you should think at variable names as *tags* for objects.
In our case we are not assigning the values contained in `dear_old_values` to `new_values`, we are simply saying that the object referenced by `dear_old_values` will now be also referenced by `new_values`.
You can check the ID of your object to confirm this:

```
dear_old_value = ["rusty_value0", "rusty_value1", "rusty_value2", "rusty_value3"]

new_values = dear_old_value

print id(dear_old_value) # 50779920
print id(new_values)     # 50779920
```

To avoid this, we initialize our variable (`new_values`) as a new `list` object (with a *different* position in memory), then we push the items in `dear_old_varables` into it.
If you check now the IDs you'll get this result:

```
dear_old_value = ["rusty_value0", "rusty_value1", "rusty_value2", "rusty_value3"]

new_values = list(dear_old_value)

print id(dear_old_value) # 41342736
print id(new_values)     # 41358240
```

Keep in mind that **all** the objects in Python behaves like this.

Comment: This means that I suppose that somewhere before the code you posted you wrote `dupys = ys`

Comment: you are right! I did write 'dupys = ys' before the code. So in python, I should not directly make two lists equal each other? I am kinda confused by how python work and I dont know why this is happening. I mainly used C++ before, this is the first time i program with python.

Comment: I've extended the answer, maybe now its not only *working*, but is also clear what is going on!

Comment: Thank you so much!